# What is AppsFlyerConversionListener and onAppOpenAttribution?

Tags: appsflyer

The documentation on AppsFlyer is circular on the most basic concepts ("To obtain AppsFlyer conversion data from the Android SDK, implement AppsFlyerConversionListener.").

- What is exactly triggered here?
- Why should I react to it?
- How would I react to it?
- Isn't the data tracked to the backend if I don't do anything here?

Answer (score 0):

We have built a branch new AppsFlyer Developer Hub to answer your questions.

Specifically `onAppOpenAttribution` is explained in details [here for Android](https://dev.appsflyer.com/docs/deep-linking-existing-app-users-to-specific-content) and [here for iOS](https://dev.appsflyer.com/docs/direct-deep-linking).

Both have fully functional Github examples.

If you questions remained unanswered, please post them.

Regards

Comment: Yeah, where's the same thing for AppsFlyerConversionListener?

Comment: You can find [here](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-onelink-android-sample-apps/blob/5b202b983b33d62bd5d80102ab27f17e2b1cb25f/java/basic_app/app/src/main/java/com/appsflyer/onelink/appsflyeronelinkbasicapp/MainActivity.java#L31-L79) a sample app that demonstrates the use of `AppsFlyerConversionListener`.

Comment: If you wish to have more info about `AppsFlyerConversionListener` you can find it in this [doc](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032126-Android-SDK-integration-for-developers#integration-32-initializing-the-sdk)